# Azure point to site vpn connection failing

Tags: vpn, azure, point-to-site-vpn

Yesterday, I made a virtual network gateway and configured point to site vpn on it. I used makecert to make the root cert and a client cert. Yesterday, it worked fine. Today, Windows says "The network connection was aborted by the local system. (Error 0x800704d4) For customized troubleshooting information for this connection, click Help."

I have recreated the certs, dropped the vpn connection and reinstalled it, rebooted, and so forth. No resolution. Can anyone offer any insight into what might be going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Check your proxy settings inside the Internet explorer. If the
>   settings are correct, please ensure you are able to access other web
>   sites (e.g. www.microsoft.com) using the browser.
>
> If that also works through, try accessing the URI which SSTP uses
>   internally i.e.
>   [https://vpn_server_name/sra_{BA195980-CD49-458b-9E23-C84EE0ADCD75}/](https://vpn_server_name/sra_%7BBA195980-CD49-458b-9E23-C84EE0ADCD75%7D/)
>   -  please replace vpn_server_name with actual VPN server name.
>
> If you see error “the website cannot be found” inside your browser,
>   that validates the hostname resolution failure. If you know the IP
>   address of VPN server, try connecting with that. Else contact your
>   network administrator (who is responsible for managing the web proxy –
>   most probably your ISP) – giving them the details of the problem (i.e.
>   hostname resolution is failing for that particular hostname).

This article will help further:

[Troubleshooting common VPN related errors](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/rrasblog/2009/08/12/troubleshooting-common-vpn-related-errors/)

Comment: It turned out that our Global IT organization was blocking the connection for 24 hours. They utilize some Cisco Umbrella service that discovers and blocks new sub domains and domains.